# Ways to generate word-frequency plot w/ Python?

Tags: python, plot

I have a file that contains a word and the frequency that it occurs. I would like to generate a sort of plot; I'm looking for a sort of 'bubble' like graph. The idea is that the size of these bubbles corresponds to the relative frequencies and the corresponding word is labeled on these bubbles. Does anyone know if this can be done with the standard matplotlib or anything similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of libraries out [there](https://python-graph-gallery.com/wordcloud/).

Here's an example from [WordCloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Minimal Example
===============
Generating a square wordcloud from the US constitution using default arguments.
"""

import os

from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# using word frequency list:
#word_freq = open("/tmp/word_freq.txt").read()
# say it looks like this:
word_freq = {'apple': 4, 'banana': 1, 'melon': 2, 'strawberry': 3, 'grape': 8}
text = " ".join([(k + " ")*v for k,v in word_freq.items()])

# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)


# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")

# lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

# The pil way (if you don't have matplotlib)
# image = wordcloud.to_image()
# image.show()
```

WordCloud from different text:
[image: wordcloud]

Comment: Yes this looks nice, but this assumes that I have the entire text. All I have are the words and the frequency. Is there a way to work with this besides generating a dummy file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the frequency data in dict `data`

Following code should work

import os

```
from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Bla': 10,
    'Bl': 2,
    'cold' : 9,
    'random': 6
}
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(" ".join([(k + ' ') * v for k,v in data.items()]))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```